# In GA, tracking user who come back to site from email verification

Tags: google-analytics

I planning new website tracking with GA.

In sign-up process, email verification makes users have to leave website(After input their address).
It sends out a link to user's email asking to confirm their address.

In the sequence

1. Input email
2. E-mail verification (exit to their address)
3. Link confirmed (back to website)
4. Input personal info(name, phone number, address etc.)
5. Sign up complete

As a Marketer, i don't know how to tracking this exit and set up Funnel goal.

Comment: I don't know for sure, but wouldn't you simply add a querystring to the URL e.g. example.com?id=123456&verification-code=%hf#30*71829&action=confirm